# how to move photos to sd card on VFD 300

Tags: internal-storage

I can browse my photos on the phone's HD, it even says at the top select destination, but there doesn't seem to be a way to actually do that! I've set it so all new photos are saved to the SD card, but the ones already on the phone I can't seem to move.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the gallery app or your file manager to manually move your pictures/videos

**Gallery**

1. Open your gallery
2. Open the album you want to move
3. Long press on any picture
4. On the top left of your screen, press "select all"
5. I'm the menu press "move" or "cut"
6. Select a folder on your sd card to move the items to, or create a new one

**File manager**

1. Open your file manager
2. Find the pictures you want to move
3. Long press on one of them, and press "select all"
4. In the menu press "move" or "cut"
5. Select a folder on your sd card to move the items to, or create a new one